# Error when running HQL query via command line

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql, hue

I am running a query via command line and am getting this error.

CMD: hive -e query1.hql

FAILED: ParseException line 1:0 cannot recognize input near 'query1' '.' 'hql'

```
CREATE TABLE dcarlo.new_table AS

SELECT ma.name, ma.address, ma.state 
FROM main_db AS ma
WHERE ma.dt>=20180301 AND ma.dt<=20180331;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `-f` instead of `-e` for running scripts from file.

```
 hive -f query1.hql
```

[Source](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+Cli#LanguageManualCli-HiveCommandLineOptions)

usage: hive

-d,--define key=value          Variable substitution to apply to Hive
                                  commands. e.g. -d A=B or --define A=B

-e "quoted-query-string"       SQL from command line

**-f filename                  SQL from files**

-H,--help                      Print help information

-h hostname                    Connecting to Hive Server on remote host
    --hiveconf property=value   Use value for given property
    --hivevar key=value         Variable substitution to apply to hive
                                  commands. e.g. --hivevar A=B

-i filename                    Initialization SQL file

-p port                        Connecting to Hive Server on port number

-S,--silent                    Silent mode in interactive shell

-v,--verbose                   Verbose mode (echo executed SQL to the
                                  console)